# What is `docker serve` command

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, wsl-2, docker-desktop

Sometimes in WSL distributions that I've marked to enable for "integration" I can see process with:

```
docker serve --address /root/.docker/run/docker-cli-api.sock
```

`docker serve --help` states it's "Start an api server". This socket seems implement non-http-based protocol unlike standard `/var/run/docker.sock`.

I can't find any references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This search on GitHub](https://github.com/search?l=&q=%22Start+an+api+server%22+user%3Adocker&type=code) pointed me to the source code. It seems to open several different servers for Docker components [here](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/blob/54020db51730a43289f2d314919e2a3977a236b6/cli/cmd/serve.go#L68-L83) and then start a grpc server:

```
    composev1.RegisterComposeServer(s, p)
    containersv1.RegisterContainersServer(s, p)
    contextsv1.RegisterContextsServer(s, p.ContextsProxy())
    streamsv1.RegisterStreamingServer(s, p)
    volumesv1.RegisterVolumesServer(s, p)
    
    ...

    // start the GRPC server to serve on the listener
    return s.Serve(listener)
```

Sorry, I have not found any reference or documentation for this and hope this is at least slightly helpful.